# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener, divide

I tried to make a nav opener with some dots HTML and CSS working fine but the script does not work properly. any help is very much appreciated.

**My Code:**

```js
const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".item-menu");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".list");


burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: cursive, sans-serif, fantasy;
  background-color: #f3f3f4
}

nav {
  height: 12vh;
  background-color: #0303;
  display: block;
}

.item-menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.a
/* menu words */

{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
}


/*---------------------------------PHONE---------------------------------*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  /*   BURGER NAV DOTS    */
  .dot {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  #burger:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #burger:hover .dot:nth-child(1) {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff900;
  }
  #burger:hover .dot:nth-child(2) {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #08ff28;
  }
  #burger:hover .dot:nth-child(3) {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff005a;
  }
  #burger:hover .dot:nth-child(4) {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #3896ff;
  }
  /*       DOTS       */
  #burger .dot:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #fff900;
    animation: animate 2s linear inifinite;
  }
  #burger .dot:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #08ff28;
    animation: animate 2s linear inifinite;
  }
  #burger .dot:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #ff005a;
    animation: animate 2s linear inifinite;
  }
  #burger .dot:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #3896ff;
    animation: animate 2s linear inifinite;
  }
  #burger {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  nav {
    position: relative;
  }
  .item-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2%;
    left: -5%;
    height: 85vh;
    width: 100%;
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 692px 612px);
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 0px 692px 612px);
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    width: 84%;
    height: 84%;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
  }
  .item-menu.open {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 692px 0px);
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 0px 692px 0px);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> BURGER NAV </title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--STYLESHEET-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div id="burger">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>

    <ul class="item-menu">
      <li class="list"><a class="a" href=""> Home </a></li>
      <li class="list"><a class="a" href=""> Portfoglio </a></li>
      <li class="list"><a class="a" href=""> Experiences </a></li>
      <li class="list"><a class="a" href=""> About me </a></li>
      <li class="list"><a class="a" href=""> Contact </a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

**My problem:**

Well, it looks like the button does not work properly and I don't understand why. They told me the script is not loaded and to put it at the end of the body and already was. I tried to change some classes, to add more classes, to do a function....nothing of the above worked...

Please I need help...I'm almost on the point of a breakdown :)) =)) Maybe coding is not for me :X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the querySelector of 'burger' set it to 
`const burger = document.querySelector("#burger");`
it's an id so we use '#' the dot '.' is for the class

Answer (score 2):

[HTML DOM querySelector() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document. So for getting elements by Id you should use [HTML DOM getElementById() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value.

```
const burger = document.getElementById("burger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".item-menu");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".list");

burger.addEventListener("click", () => 
{
    navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
});
```